# Swift Programmatic UI where can I put all the constraints?

Tags: swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

So I started to learn Programmatic UI after I struggled with Storyboard.

I basically figured out where can I store the View's code such as button, textfield, etc.

But my problem is I don't want to see all the constraints below in my VC.

**Is there any way to store all these constraints somewhere or coding some function to call them every time I want to add constraints?**

I know it is gonna be longer when I add more components...

For example;

```
  func configureTextField() {
    self.view.addSubview(usernameTextField)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      self.usernameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.logoImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
      self.usernameTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40),
      self.usernameTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -40),
      self.usernameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
    ])
  }
```

Comment: No pictures of code please. That helps no one. I can't even see it, let alone edit or run it.

Comment: "no pictures of code" doesn't mean "no code". Please edit to include your code *as text*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're just complaining that autolayout constraint code is verbose. And you know what? You're right! It *is* verbose. It's not as verbose as it used to be, but it's still verbose.

There are three solutions that programmers use:

- **Make use of stack views**. When views line up horizontally or vertically, you can use a single stack view to arrange them. A stack view is a view that *creates* constraints. Thus, you don't have to create those constraints yourself (though you do have to create, configure, and constrain the stack view).
- **Write convenience methods**. For example, our team has methods like `addConstrained(subview:top:left:bottom:right:)`. We still have to write a boatload of constraint code but it's a lot simpler and shorter than writing it all out one anchor at a time as you are doing.
- **Use a library**. Basically this is just a pre-existing collection of convenience methods. For example, many people like [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) (though personally the last thing I want in my code is yet another layer of dependency, so I don't use it myself).